# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't see any of my hard drive partitions when installing alongside Windows 10

Tags: boot, 16.04, bios

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on an older computer (6+ years). I bought a new 1TB HD and did a clean install of Windows 10. I left ~300 GB free for Ubuntu, but when I boot into the live USB and begin the install, I get to the part where it should ask "Installation Type" and there are no hard drives listed as in this [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nooa0.png). When I click on anything, the installer crashes. The computer is running in Legacy/BIOS not UEFI as far as I can tell.  [This also looked helpful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUbT8.png)

Comment: From the Windows side, look at the partitions, are they dynamic or basic?  Dynamic partitions cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

One possible culprit is fastboot. This is a feature of Windows 10 where it doesn't completely shut down so that it can boot up faster. Try turning off this feature (its in the advanced power options area of the control panel) or performing a hard shutdown (holding the power key down for a few seconds) before trying to boot into the live USB.

Comment: Instead of the hard shutdown you could also choose to restart via the normal way, and have the bootable usb already plugged in for it to run on boot.